# Spring Security4 Always getting redirected to Access is Denied after Login

Tags: java, spring

Below is my spring security configuration, the user I am trying to login with has Admin role but still it is getting redirected to access denied.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.scd" />

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:/messages"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="bcryptEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        disable-url-rewriting="false">
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin.xhtml"
            access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?auth=fail"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />


        <logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" />

    </http>
    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean
        class="com.scd.security.CustomAuthenticationHandler"
        id="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"></beans:bean>

    <!-- Authentication-manager Bean -->
    <!-- Set customUserDetailsService class as the authentication Manager for 
        Spring Security -->
    <authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login" />
        <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username" />
        <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: As i need this to be solved immediately, i added that phrase. still I didnot understand your point halfer ..sorry

Comment: The short version of that link is that volunteers are under no obligation to help you to suit your own deadlines. They probably will object to your belief that your question is more important than other people's questions here too. If you read the link I have offered, it will explain this all in plenty of detail.

Comment: Sorry, But I havent mentioned that my question is more important than others. Just want to mention that somebody has already answered this in Spring forum meeting my urgency.Thank you for your suggestions halfer

Comment: Righto. If your solution would be of use to other engineers, feel free to add an answer below.